# How to freeze a part of dashboard body in R Shiny?

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

1. I have an R Shiny dashboard.
2. In its body, I have some user inputs located in the top part of the body, e.g. sliders and text inputs.
3. Underneath user inputs, I have charts that are being rendered when a user changes inputs.
4. There are several charts located in several rows, therefore a user needs to scroll down to go through all of them.
5. I want to freeze the upper part of the dashboard body, so when a user scrolls down, all user inputs are still being visible. Something similar to Excel's "Freeze Rows" functionality.

How do I do that?

Comment: https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/absolutely-positioned-panels.html This may help you

Comment: Can you post a mwe so we could dig into the underlying html and see what modifications may be necessary

Comment: @LocoGris, thank you. If you post this as an answer I'll accept it as the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the function absolutePanel() from the library markdown. It is exactly what you are looking for!
I'm attaching a hyperlink of the same below.
[Absolutely Positioned Panels](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/absolutely-positioned-panels.html)